# Select displayed rows based on user criteria

Tags: vba, date

I have looked but not found a solution to the task I am attempting.  I am new to VBA so the learning curve is steep.  Here is what I am trying to do:

In Excel 2010/2013, I have a worksheet with fixed content in the top 9 rows, and starting with row 10, rows of data with consecutive dates in column B.  I need users to be able to evaluate data within a certain subset of all the dates in the sheet.

For example:  User enters the values "06/15/15" in cell K1, and "06/19/15" in cell N1.  Rows 10 through 20 each contain a record, with column B being the date field for each record.  In this example, cell B10 contains the date 06/12/15 through cell B20 which contains the date 06/22/15.  I need the code to look at the contents of cells K1 and N1, interpret them as boundaries of a date range, and display only the rows of data that both have a row value of 10 or greater and are within that defined range, hiding all the others, leaving the header rows 1 through 9 visible.  Only the rows greater than 9, with dates between and inclusive of the user selected criteria should be visible.

Comment: If you post your attempt of writing this code, we can then help with any problems you may be having with it. SO is not a code request service.

Comment: @iturner - I understand what you are saying but my attempts have not resulted in anything useful and I deleted them when they didn't work.  I am too new to this I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
dim iRow as integer
dim iColumn as integer

iRow = 10     'Row 10
iColumn = 2   'Column B

do until activesheet.cells(iRow, iColumn).value = ""
    if datediff("d", activesheet.range("K1").value, _
        activesheet.cells(iRow, iColumn).value) => -10 AND _
        datediff("d", activesheet.range("N1").value, _
        activesheet.cells(iRow, iColumn).value) =< 10 then _
        activesheet.rows(iRow).entirerow.hidden = true
    iRow = iRow + 1
loop
```

If you need to check multiple columns, you can add an extra loop inside of this loop with an iColumn = iColumn + 1. Is this what you were looking for?